# php 'if statement' to check array for duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

**I've created the following**

```
$usernames = $db->fetchColumn('Select username from profiles');
```

**It creates the following**

> Array ( [0] => todd [1] => test [2] => brent_test [3] => danny [4] => alyssa [5] => dogg )

I do **NOT** want to check an array for duplicates in it. I want to check to see if an array has a value in it. If the array ($usernames)does have the value of $var in it, I want it to rerun 'true'. If array ($usernames)does not have the value of $var in it, I want it to return 'false'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should check for duplicates in your SQL query instead.

Comment: check out this function: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @john How do I remove the 'duplicate' from this question? It does not ask the same thing as the question you've linked to. Thanks

Comment: If you're looking to check if an array has a value in it use `in_array` http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: @ToddBenrud It's a dupe. The solution you seek is in there.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. 

`if (in_array("$username", $usernames)) {
 echo "$username already exists. Please select a different username.";
 }
 else {
        echo "$username does not exist";
        }
`